# How to create methods at the end of the class with "quick fix" feature in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

when I type a call to non-existent yet method, I can generate the method skeleton by clicking "quick fix -> create method".
all cool so far, but the method is usually generated right behind the method where Im calling this new method. for example :

```
public void myTest() {
 newMethod(); // I type this and then click "generate method"
}
// method is generated here
private void newMethod() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void anotherTest() { }
public void oneMoreTest() { }
```

What do I do to get the method generated at the end ? like this :

```
public void myTest() {
 newMethod(); // I type this and then click "generate method"
}
public void anotherTest() { }
public void oneMoreTest() { }
// I'd like the method generated here.
private void newMethod() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: Good question, also looking for this...